# Enhancing the Custom Filter capability

Tags: discussion, feature-request, custom-filter

The introduction of the "Custom Filter" capability was a great idea. But for a while I have found it to be limited.  Why not include most, if not all, of the available search/filter options?  But at a minimum include boolean operators.  I especially would like to see closed and duplicate added.  Presently, those options must be added manually each time and then the sort order must be adjusted to newest.

Comment: See also [Add option "not closed" to the custom filters](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/355243/323179)

Comment: @laurel Thank you for pointing that out.  I did search but it didn't pop up.

Comment: cross-site duplicate of [Add an advanced search option to custom filtering](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/387345/997587) on MSE